# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:

Tags: android, runtime-error

I have the following code:

```
package Business;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Model.Categoria;
import Utilities.SQLHelper;
import developer.negabur.chistes.R;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class CategoriasFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListView lstCategorias;
    private ArrayList<Categoria> listCategoria;
    private CategoriasAdapter adapter;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private SQLHelper dbh;


    public CategoriasFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        //dbh = new SQLHelper(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "chistes.db", null, 2);
        //db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();


        listCategoria = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
        listCategoria.add(new Categoria (1, "hola"));


        lstCategorias = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lstCategorias);
        adapter = new CategoriasAdapter(getActivity(), listCategoria);


        lstCategorias.setAdapter(adapter);


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categorias, container, false);
    }
}
```

When i try to execute my app brokes and display the following message:

```
 10-18 13:30:08.909    4134-4134/d E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at developer.negabur.chistes.Categorias.onCreate(Categorias.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at Business.CategoriasFragment.onCreateView(CategoriasFragment.java:51)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:924)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1116)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1218)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2170)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:842)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:830)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at developer.negabur.chistes.Categorias.onCreate(Categorias.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve? I Did not find what I am doing wrong. It seems a problem with the getActivity(), when I Get the "lstCategorias" but do not know how can I resolve that.

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Correct way

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categorias, container, false);

    listCategoria = new ArrayList<Categoria>();
    listCategoria.add(new Categoria (1, "hola"));

    lstCategorias = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lstCategorias);
    adapter = new CategoriasAdapter(getActivity(), listCategoria);

    lstCategorias.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Lol Thanks I forgoted that this is the correct Way.

Really thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try This .

```
public View FragmentView; //Global

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   if (FragmentView == null) {

        FragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categorias, container, false);


     // Do your Staff
     }
    else
     {
        ((ViewGroup) FragmentView.getParent()).removeView(FragmentView);
     }

    return FragmentView;
    }
```